# Convert List Contents To Named Elements Within Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I struggle to even describe what's going on here, but this code works:

```
list_of_lists = [
  [1.1, 1.2],
  [2.1, 2.2]
]

for (first, second) in list_of_lists:
    print("%s %s" % (first, second))

# output:
# 1.1 1.2
# 2.1 2.2
```

Where each internal list of list_of_lists has the elements converted to the variable names "first" and "second".

What is this process of naming list contents called?

Also, if I wanted to convert the result to an object equivalent of:

```
[
    {
        "first": 1.1,
        "second": 1.2
    },
    {
        "first": 2.1,
        "second": 2.2
    }
]
```

How could I do that in a list comprehension? I'm trying something like this, but am struggling to find the syntax to express what I'm trying to do, specifically with regards to ???:

```
results = [??? for (first, second) in list_of_lists]
```

I know I can do something like the more verbose:

```
results = [{"first": l[0], "second": l[1]} for l in list_of_lists]
```

...but I want to do it in a more concise form that uses names alone instead of list item indexes.

Comment: The output you show is wrong and impossible. It is `1.1 2.1
1.2 2.2`

Comment: @Pynchia - You're correct, and that was my typo. I fixed it.

Comment: `[dict(zip(('first', 'second'), lst)) for lst in list_of_lists]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process is called [Unpacking argument list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

for example:

```
a, b = [1, 2]
```

Then `a` will be equal to `1` and `b` will be equal to `2`

In your code in line

```
for (first, second) in list_of_lists
```

Each `sub-list` inside your main list `list_of_lists` is **unpacked** to two values.
For example in the first iteration of loop, `first` will be equal to `1.1` and `second` will be equal to `2.2`

Applying the same principle to the second list:

```
li = [
    {
        "first": 1.1,
        "second": 1.2
    },
    {
        "first": 2.1,
        "second": 2.2
    }
]

result = [(item['first'], item['second']) for item in li]
print(result) # [(1.1, 1.2), (2.1, 2.2)]

# OR, TO EXTRACT DICTIONARY (as pointed by Sarol)
results = [{"first": first, "second": second} for first, second in list_of_lists]

print(results) # [{'first': 1.1, 'second': 1.2}, {'first': 2.1, 'second': 2.2}]
```

The `dict()` function creates a dictionary by taking an iterable consisting of `key:value` pairs, and `x.items()` **unpacks** a dictionary `x` into its `key` and `value`.

Your specific problem required first `packing` each item of list and then `unpacking` it. So, using `list-comprehension`, iterate over the list, get `key-value` pair of each item using `items()` function, and then use `dict()` method to create a dictionary out of it. So:

```
#OR, EVEN EASILY
result = [dict(item.items()) for item in li]
print(result) # [{'first': 1.1, 'second': 1.2}, {'first': 2.1, 'second': 2.2}]
```

Comment: Great breakdown. However, if wanting to use a dictionary, is there a more concise way than duplicating variable names (e.g. {"first": first})?

Comment: What output you want finally for your `list_of_lists` variable? Then I'll see what I can do

Comment: The output is perfect, I just was wondering if {"first": first, "second": second} could be simplified by a statement that infers the key/value from the variable names.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, check the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Now how do you do it just given list_of_lists and parameter names given within the comprehension?

Comment: Wait for a few minutes, I'll add the explanation in the answer. Happy to help, by the way

Comment: @Colin I've added the explanation. You can now see it in the answer

Comment: wait, why are you starting from the expected result (array of dict)? wasn't the stating data suppose to be a list of lists?

Comment: and what does `[dict(item.items()) for item in li]` actually change?

Answer (score 6):

Unpack the tuples from list_of_lists as you iterate over it.

```
results = [{"first": first, "second": second} for first, second in list_of_lists]
```

Comment: Is there a way to just use the variable names of the unpacked tuple automatically, though?

Comment: Not as far as I can figure. There might be a way, but I think it would be worse than just doing it as I showed.